# Unable to retrieve ITextDocument from HTML text buffer

Tags: document, visual-studio-extensions

Using the following code I am able to get the ITextDocument for .css and .js files and more, but the DocumentService.TryGetTextDocument() method is returning a null out ITextDocument document for **.html** files.

```
[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument)]
internal sealed class CommandProvider : IVsTextViewCreationListener
{
    [Import(typeof(IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService))]
    private IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService EditorService { get; set; }

    [Import(typeof(ITextDocumentFactoryService))]
    private ITextDocumentFactoryService DocumentService { get; set; }

    public void VsTextViewCreated(IVsTextView textViewAdapter)
    {
        var textView = EditorService.GetWpfTextView(textViewAdapter);
        if (!DocumentService.TryGetTextDocument(textView.TextBuffer, out ITextDocument document))
            return;
    }
}
```

Question: How can I retrieve the ITextDocument from a HTML text buffer?

I need to manipulate the content of the document when executing a specific command.

Any help greatly appeciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code like this, it works on my side.

```
public void VsTextViewCreated(IVsTextView textViewAdapter)
{
    var textView = EditorService.GetWpfTextView(textViewAdapter);
    ITextDocument document = null;
    if (!DocumentService.TryGetTextDocument(textView.TextDataModel.DocumentBuffer, out document))
        return;
}
```

Comment: Changing the first argument to **DocumentService.TryGetTextDocument** from **textView.TextBuffer** to **textView.TextDataModel.DocumentBuffer** works. Thank you!